# Removing drawn shape object

Tags: java, swing, awt, shapes, graphics2d

I am trying to build a simple paint using Shape java build-in,  How can I remove/delete the shape (for example a circle) from the JFrame?

```
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.util.List;

public class Delete extends DrawingPanel {
    List<ShapeItem> shape;
    public Delete(List<ShapeItem> shape){
        this.shape = shape;
    }
    public void deleteShape(){
        for(ShapeItem s : shape){
            if(s.getShape() instanceof Line2D){
                s.setColor(getBackground());
            }
            if(s.getShape() instanceof Ellipse2D){
                s.setColor(getBackground());
            }
            if(s.getShape() instanceof Rectangle2D){
                s.setColor(getBackground());
            }
            if(s.getShape() instanceof Polygon ){
                s.setColor(getBackground());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Is this way is valid?

Comment: Why are you making an entirely separate class to delete a shape? Surely this could be conducted in the main class, right? To delete a shape I would just simply stop drawing it. This should be handled wherever this drawing process is conducted, I would think.

Comment: Why not `List#remove()`?

Comment: I would also advise against this implementation because it doesn't actually delete the shape, it just sets it to the color of the background. Yes, use something like `shapes[i].remove()`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).